# How many Allocations can TURN server create?

Tags: webrtc, turn, coturn, rfc5766turnserver

I am talking about Nat Traversal. There is a limit to the UDP port number of a server. So i think a TURN server can create 64k Allocations total which means only 64k clients can communicate with other peers though a TURN server at a time.
Is there a way to break the limit and have more clients to communicate without import more TURN server.